# Operation on consecutive numbers in a python list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to write a function that accepts a list of integers as an argument. It will then find all runs of 3 consecutive numbers that increase or decrease by 1. It will return the list of indices of the first element of each run. If there are no consecutive runs it should return `None`.
Example: `[1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 9, 8, 9, 10, 11, 7, 8, 7]` returns `[0, 4, 6, 7]`.  Any help on how I can break this down will be appreciated.

My attempt gave me the wrong output:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 9, 8, 9, 10, 11, 7, 8, 7]


def cal_abs(a, b, c):

  return abs(a - b) == 1 and abs(b - c) == 1

def consecutive(lst):

   a = []

   for i in range(0,lst[-1]):

       if cal_abs(lst[i], lst[i+1], lst[i+2]):

           a.append(i)

          i += 1

   print(a)
```

Now when I ran `consecutive(lst)`

It returns `[0, 4, 5, 6]`. WRONG. Any ideas?

Comment: "If there are no consecutive runs it should return None." Note that this is a bad idea, as it changes the return type and can lead to corrupted data if a check is missed. Either: 1) return an empty list, which is consistent with returning a list of all matches. 2) raise an exception, which prevents silently propagating a wrong value.

Comment: Thanks @MisterMiyagi Figure it out, it was my cal_abs function.  Made the change to return abs(a - b) == 1 and abs(a - c) == 2

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems. I'll give you some hints that should be sufficient to figure out and fix them.

This:

```
return abs(a - b) == 1 and abs(b - c) == 1
```

accepts an increase followed by a decrease, and vice versa. This doesn't quite fit your problem statement, which appears to require either two increases or two decreases.

Also, the upper bound on the main loop, `lst[-1]`, takes *the value of the last element* - why?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check either a > b > c or a < b < c. you can see the code below

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 9, 8, 9, 10, 11, 7, 8, 7]

def cal_abs(a, b, c):
    if a < b and b < c and (a-b) == -1 and (b-c) == -1:
        return True
    elif a > b and b > c and (a-b) == 1 and (b-c) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def consecutive(lst):
    a = []
    for i in range(0,len(lst)-3):
        if cal_abs(lst[i], lst[i+1], lst[i+2]):
            a.append(i)
            i += 1
    print(a)

consecutive(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making a helper function called `isARun(f, m, l)`

```
def isARun(f,m,l):
    return (f == m-1 and f == l-2) or (f == m + 1 and f == l+2)
```

Then you want to do a for loop in your main function `consecutive` that looks like this.

```
for i in range(len(l) - 3):
    if (isARun(l[i], l[i+1], l[i+2])):
        a.append(i)
if len(a) == 0:
    return None
return a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple solution:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 9, 8, 9, 10, 11, 7, 8, 7]

consective_indices = []
for index, num in enumerate(my_list[:-2]):
    immediate_next = abs(my_list[index + 1])
    next = abs(my_list[index + 2])
    if (num + 1 == immediate_next and num + 2 == next) or 
              (num - 1 == immediate_next and num - 2 == next):

        consective_indices.append(index)

print consective_indices
```

hope this helps. Cheers !